# Sci-fi anime about guy who finds dying alien and gets transformation power through somersault

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I seem to remember that he helps a crashed/dying bluish skinned alien and in return gets the power to transform/get armour when doing a somersault. I think the crashed UFO looked kind of like a flying car.

At the end of the movie there is a fight with a big mecha...

Comment: I remember it was a VHS movie that my friend had.

Comment: Sounds very much like a *tokusatsu* series. Was this a somersault (on the ground) or a flip (in the air)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[GOLDWING 1978](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0416781/)*, also known as *Hwanggeum Nalgae 1.2.3.*. It's a Korean anime.

> Jack O'Neil is an ordinary boy who once accidentally saves the life of a newcomer from an alien planet. Unfortunately, the alien dies, but before his death he gives Jack his super power and mission to save the world from the invasion of the cosmic evil empire. From now on, in case of danger, Jack transforms into a powerful warrior, Goldwing. The boy is an orphan raised by a scientist who has developed plans to build a giant war robot. Unfortunately, Aliens are getting these plans and building a powerful robot according to them. Now the whole hope of the world is Goldwing, which in the fight against the invaders helps a robot in the shape of a black leopard, which, if necessary, can serve as a flying vehicle.

[image: Front cover of Hwanggeum Nalgae 1.2.3.]

Comment: Brilliant! Thats the one! It has been bugging me for close to 30 years! Thankyouthankyouthankyou!