# 80's/90's animated kids show: guy doing somersault to enter his ship

Tags: story-identification, tv, robots, animation

There's a guy that would do a forward/backward somersault off a big rock/cliff (then "morphs" into his armor) into a large body of water to enter his flying ship (like a spaceship but not for space).

The ship is a combo of a giant robot in the middle of a round/oval "body" with its arms wrapped around the sides and its head sticking out the front. Not sure about its legs and feet.

At some point the operator have the robot eject from the round body to become a stand-alone robot fighter.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: My first thought was *Mighty Orbots*, but then opening doesn't match.

Comment: After fast-forwarding through two versions of *Taekwon V*, I'm pretty sure that's not the answer either.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the 1978 Korean cartoon *[Goldwing](https://screenanarchy.com/2010/05/korean-animation-goldwing-1-2-3-bluray-review.html)* as per [Sci-fi anime about guy who finds dying alien and gets transformation power through somersault](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126553/sci-fi-anime-about-guy-who-finds-dying-alien-and-gets-transformation-power-throu/194884)

> Young shy orphan Hyun lives with Professor Lee, who is designing a giant flying robot to help mankind. One day, Hyun comes across a badly wounded alien who crashed in a ravine, and he helps the humanoid creature reach its secret hideout. The alien turns out to be a policeman who is hunting an escaped criminal of his own species. The villain is on Earth after having kidnapped the policeman's daughter, and unfortunately he managed to ambush his pursuer. The dying policeman transforms Hyun into "Gold Wing 1": a masked superhero with a computer-steered armor and a robot panther sidekick called "Gold Wing 2". The alien then dies, but not before asking Hyun to save his daughter. He also warns Hyun that the Gold Wing armor can only be used for fighting evil, and that Hyun must keep his new identity a secret or risk losing the suit...

The somersalt transformation can be seen around minute 47 [here](https://archive.org/details/01-goldwing-1980-).

Found with search terms of `80s cartoon robot somersault`

Comment: If this is correct, you can click on the checkmark by the voting buttons to accept it.

Comment: Tnx but unfortunately that's not the one. The character dives directly into the water and swims to his robot-ship...under the water.

Answer (score 1):

[*"UFO Robot Grendizer"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grendizer) fits your description as a <strike>glove</strike> rocket punch.

It's a Japanese series first aired in 1975 and subsequently dubbed and broadcast in many other countries.
While in Japan it wasn't particularly well-received by the public at the time and is almost forgotten nowadays, the show was particularly successful in Europe where it was one of the first imported robotic anime series and started a "robot mania" that lasted for years; is is still fondly remembered by a lot of people.

> The ship is a combo of a giant robot in the middle of a round/oval "body" with its arms wrapped around the sides and its head sticking out the front. Not sure about its legs and feet.

[image: Grendizer inside the Spacer ship]

> At some point the operator have the robot eject from the round body to become a stand-alone robot fighter.

This matches too, as Grendizer can detach from the flying saucer (called Spacer) and jump on top of it, or just go its way.

> There's a guy that would do a forward/backward somersault off a big rock/cliff (then "morphs" into his armor) into a large body of water to enter his flying ship (like a spaceship but not for space).

In the first episode the pilot rides a motorbike, jumps off a cliff and dives into a lake to reach the subterranean hangar from where the ship is launched.